# Positiveness of two variable inequality

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, inequalities

How to show that the function

```
g[a_, n_] = -4 a^2 + 8 a^3 - 4 a^4 + 16 a n - 24 a^2 n + 8 a^3 n - 
        12 n^2 - 4 a n^2 + 12 a^2 n^2 + 12 n^3 - 8 a n^3
```

of two variables is positive in $a\in (2,n-2)$ with $2 \leq n < \infty$?

Comment: An easy way to check is just to plot it and at it :)  `Plot3D[g,{n,2,100},{a,2,98},PlotRange->All]`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bdR7r.png) so it is indeed can be negative in this domain.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Roman  It is not clear to me that your edit of the question is correct, because it no longer agrees with the image, which you deleted.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I checked again and think my edits were correct. What difference do you see?

Comment: @Roman  They do not agree with the content of the image. which placed limits of `2 <= n <= 100 && 2 <= a <= 98` on the two variables.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I took that to mean that the OP didn't know how to specify infinity and replaced it by a large number (100). Please edit back if you think I misunderstood.

Comment: @Roman  I am more concerned about the range of `a`.  If course, our disagreement may be insignificant.  If you think so, I can delete my comments.

Answer (score 3):

This function  is not always positive for `2 <= n <= 100 && 2 <= a <= 98`, as can be shown by

```
g = -4 a^2 + 8 a^3 - 4 a^4 + 16 a n - 24 a^2 n + 8 a^3 n - 12 n^2 - 
    4 a n^2 + 12 a^2 n^2 + 12 n^3 - 8 a n^3;
t = Flatten[Table[{a, n, g}, {n, 2, 100}, {a, 2, 98}], 1]
Select[t, Last[#] <= 0 &]
Length@%

(* {{2, 2, 64}, {3, 2, 192}, {4, 2, 304}, {5, 2, 208}, {6, 2, -384}, …} *)
(* 4055 *)
```

Two other methods to find negative values for `g` are

```
Minimize[{g, 2 <= n <= 100 && 2 <= a <= 98}, {a, n}]
(* {-346401728, {a -> 98, n -> 2}} *)

FindInstance[{g < 0, 2 <= n <= 100 && 2 <= a <= 98}, {a, n}, 
    Integers] // Flatten
g /. %
(* {a -> 12, n -> 3} *)
(* -25272 *)
```

Comment: is using `FindMinimum` then like I did in comment wrong for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: fyi, this is the `g` I used `g = -4 a^2 + 8 a^3 - 4 a^4 + 16 a n - 24 a^2 n + 8 a^3 n - 12 n^2 -  4 a n^2 + 12 a^2 n^2 + 12 n^3 - 8 a n^3`;

Comment: @Nasser Try `Minimize` instead.  Remember that `FindMinimum` gives a local minimum, and `Minimize` give a global minimum, in this case `{-346401728, {a -> 98, n -> 2}}`.

Comment: Yes, I read that `FindMinimum` gives local min. But the region is constrained. So I thought will make it given global min in that region. I wonder then how it finds this min then. But good to know.. I'll remember to use `Minimize` next time.

Comment: You are correct, I checked by just plotting it. This is the lazy way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
g[a_, n_] = -4 a^2 + 8 a^3 - 4 a^4 + 16 a n - 24 a^2 n + 8 a^3 n - 
            12 n^2 - 4 a n^2 + 12 a^2 n^2 + 12 n^3 - 8 a n^3;

ForAll[a, 2 < a < n - 2, g[a, n] >= 0] // Resolve

(*    n <= 6.64594    *)
```

So your statement is false for $n>6.64594$.

If you want to know for what values of $a$ the function is nonnegative (for fixed $n$), you can do

```
With[{n = 100},
  g[a, n] >= 0 && 2 <= a <= n - 2 // Reduce]

(*    52.4399 <= a <= 98    *)

With[{n = 1000},
  g[a, n] >= 0 && 2 <= a <= n - 2 // Reduce]

(*    528.836 <= a <= 998    *)
```

Comment: You know n is order of graph here, its arbitrary positive integer but finite, so is a. For suppose I tried by substituting particular value of n say, 10,100,1000... Then I varied values of a from 2 to n/2 and from n/2 to n-2. In the first interval function is positive while in later function is negative for values strictly greater than n/2. In case of n=100 and a>= 54 function is positive. I need some exact method which confirm the negativeness of function.